# Angular ui router set current state in unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I have this simple snippet of code (the real app code is more complicated), the point is to test `$state.includes`

```
$scope.Testing (state) {
   if (!$state.includes(state)){
       $state.go(state);
   }
}
```

In unit tests, I need to set current state to be a child state of the state to be tested:

```
spyOn($state,"go");
$state.current.name = "app.subState";//set current state
$scope.Testing("app");
expect($state.go).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But the `$state.go` is still called. It looks to me setting `$state.current.name` does not have effect. Then I tried:

```
spyOn($state,"go");
$state.transitionTo("app.subState");//set current state.
$scope.Testing("app");
expect($state.go).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But looks like `$state.transitionTo` fires real http request and ends up with an error like: `Error: Unexpected request: GET /state.html`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you probably have set `templateUrl` and ui-router will try to fetch it by using an http call.
You can either use [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) to intercept the request and return something instead, or use [Karma html-to-js processor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) which will insert your html files into a module so everything will be fetched from the template cache instead.

Comment: using Karma html-to-js processor is a good idea, but if we trigger a real state change, all the code to initialize the state will run which could send further real https

Comment: I don't think the ui-view isn't really compiled in such unit tests, so the controller will not be invoked. I just tried a very simple state with a controller that creates an `$http` request, and loaded the state in my unit test. It didn't alert for unexpected requests, so I tend to believe it won't be a problem, although further testing is needed.